# How can I save todo tasks using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

I'm making a new ToDo list and I want to save the tasks/projects on localStorage, using Vue.js

I have already make todo list using JS, and tried to save innerHTML/TextContent to localStorage like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('tasks', tasks.innerHTML);
```

Preview:
https://codepen.io/Eslare/pen/QWKXzvd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a state management to best save your values and manage how they are save in the local storage.

In vue, the most popular one is `vuex`. you can see it's documentation [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

You can also read about how to later on connect vuex and local storage [here](https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-permanently-save-data-with-vuex-localstorage-in-your-vue-app-f1d5c140db69).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just push the object itself to the localStorage using `JSON.stringify`:

```
 addTask: function() {
      this.todos.push({
        id: this.todos.length + 1,
        name: this.newTask,
        completed: false
      });

      localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(this.todos));

      this.newTask = '';
    }
```

You can then load the tasks back in, in your mounted function after you reload the page using `JSON.parse`:

```
mounted(){
  this.todos = JSON.parse(localStoarge.getItem('tasks'));
}
```